# SQL: Sum(colA-colB) vs Sum(colA)-sum(colB)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is:

```
select sum(colA)-sum(colB) from Table
```

The same as:

```
select sum(colA-colB) from Table
```

It seems so, but just checking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are different: **if** you have `NULLs` in your data.  Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ColA INT, ColB INT)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (ColA, ColB) VALUES (5,2)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (ColA, ColB) VALUES (5,NULL)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (ColA, ColB) VALUES (NULL,2)


SELECT SUM(ColA) - SUM(ColB) FROM @TestTable 
SELECT SUM(ColA - ColB) FROM @TestTable
```

The first query will return 6 (10 - 4), while the second query will return 3 (5-2 plus 5-NULL plus NULL-2).  Each time a NULL value is used in a direct calculation, the calculation will return NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all.  In particular, they handle `NULL` values differently.  So, consider:

```
A     B
1     NULL
2     2
NULL  2
```

The query:

```
select sum(colA) - sum(colB)
```

will return SUM(1, 2) - SUM(2, 2) = -1

The query:

```
select sum(colA - colB)
```

will return SUM(NULL, 2-2, NULL) = 0.

There are other subtle differences that can arise due to numbers having ranges.  For instance, one method could exceed computation limits and generate an error.  Or, there might be difference in decimal digits.  But the handling of `NULL`s would typically be the biggest difference.

Comment: Isn't the result 0 for `sum(colA - colB)` in your example?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You edit doesn't make sense to me. `(NULL + 4 + NULL) = 4` or even `(NULL + 4 + NULL) = NULL` would make more sense to me?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . Those are not SQL `+`.  They are SQL `SUM()`.  Clearly an ambiguous statement, so I think I made an adjustment to be clearer.

Comment: Ok, so `Sum(NULL + 4 + NULL) = 0` certainly not `Sum(NULL, 0, NULL) = 4`?!